# Is there any way to get the current http connections in SpringBoot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just want to know the active http connections to my SpringBoot application. I will refer this to estimate web users time to time. Is there any way to get this?

1. I got this answer from [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079889/how-can-i-get-the-current-number-of-client-request-threads-in-spring-boot-embedd). But this is a bit different from my environment. My application is deployed in Production Linux server, which is beyond my touch. So I cannot run any JMX tool on it.
2. I tried SpringBoot actuator. I can only get `httpsessions.active`, this is not what I want. I want http request count, not http session count.

Any help for this? Thanks.

Comment: What about ServletRequestListener, which receives notifications whenever a new request is about to come to the web application.  ?

Comment: Hi @SudhirOjha, I guess you mean that we can add some count logic in ServletRequestListener, and persist the value somewhere. Then we can view the data. Is there any third libaray other than to add extra count logic in the code?

Comment: Yes i think implementing count logic is much better than third party library, because i don't know any library regarding your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone show a way in the server to get the current connections.

> netstat -an | grep :8090 | wc -l

I think this is the direct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the metrics that spring support. There is a bit of work but should get you everything you need.

From [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html) "

> Spring MVC Metrics auto-configuration enables the instrumentation of
>   requests handled by Spring MVC. When
>   management.metrics.web.server.auto-time-requests is true, this
>   instrumentation occurs for all requests.

"

Here is a good [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-api-metrics) that you can refer to.